# How to configure Spring Security for a single page application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I faced with a problem configuration Spring Security for single page application.

So, defualt config looks like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/list").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }

    @Bean(name="authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


}
```

From the documentation for the methods for Login().loginPage("/login") says the it use for redirecting to the login page. For single page this configuration doesn't relevant.
How I should configure spring for single page application? I mean how to configure login, logout in controller and in configuration file.

Comment: You can look at [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/) for an example how to configure login using Spring as a backend and Angular as a frontend.

Answer (score 12):

[Spring Lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon) can be a complete example for this, but let me summarize the things below.

By default, when a user successfully logs in, Spring Security redirects him to the home page. When a login fails, or after a successful logout, the user is redirected back to the login page. Also, on trying to access URLs for which a user does not have sufficient rights, he is redirected to the login page.

As you say, this behavior won't suit for single page applications. Your API should instead send a 200 response along with the user data, or a 4xx response. This can be done by supplying your own handlers, like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .formLogin()
        ...
        .successHandler(your authentication success handler object)
        .failureHandler(your authentication failure handler object)
        .and()
    .logout()
        ...
        .logoutSuccessHandler(your logout success handler object)
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
    ...
}
```

You will find many examples in the Internet on how to code these handler classes. For example, in the [spring-lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon) project, these are coded as below.

**[Authentication Success Handler](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/spring-lemon-jpa/src/main/java/com/naturalprogrammer/spring/lemon/security/LemonAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java)**

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler
    extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired    
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired    
    private LemonService<?,?> lemonService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        AbstractUser<?,?> currentUser = lemonService.userForClient();

        response.getOutputStream().print(
                objectMapper.writeValueAsString(currentUser));

        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }
}
```

In summary, it returns a 200 response with the JSONified current-user in the response data.

**Authentication Failure Handler**

In fact, there is no need to code a class for the authentication failure handler - the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` provided by Spring, if instantiated without any arguments, works as desired.

**Logout Success Handler**

```
public class LemonLogoutSuccessHandler
    implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

For a detailed example, referring Spring Lemon's [LemonWebSecurityConfig](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/spring-lemon-commons-web/src/main/java/com/naturalprogrammer/spring/lemon/commonsweb/security/LemonWebSecurityConfig.java) class and other classes in it's security packages of various modules can be helpful.

Comment: Sanjay, thanks for this solution. Unfortunately the links to the handlers you list are outdated.

Comment: Oh yes, lot changed in the master branch of SpringLemon after that. I just updated the links in the post above, but now SpringLemon is stateless etc., and above answer is no more a one-to-one match.